# How do I set select multiple values?

Tags: jquery

I have a select with multiple values. I need to set those values but am not sure how this is done.

```
var values= data.record.execId;

$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
  data.form.find('select[name=execs]')
   .val(e);
});
```

The code only sets one of the two values. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The string values are: `12,14,15`

EDIT #2

In my tired stupor, I forgot to include a line of code. Here is the complete each loop as I think it should be:

```
$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
data.form.find('select[name=execs]')
  .attr({multiple:'multiple',name:'execs[]'}) <-- Forgot to include this
  .val(e);
});
```

Comment: Can you please show your values string.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, I posted the string values up top. Thanks

Comment: You are overwriting what you have set the `select`s to, in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. I'm really new to JQ so that's not surprising. Can you please show me how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the array to `val()`:

```
data.form.find("select[name=execs]").val(data.record.execId.split(","));
```

As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) says:

> Passing an array of element values allows matching `<input
>   type="checkbox">`, `<input type="radio">` and `<option>`s inside of a
>   `<select multiple="multiple">` to be selected.

Comment: Frederic, unfortunately, it only selects one of the values.

Comment: @NaN, strange, it works fine for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xB2B/). Are you sure the values of the `<option>` elements match the numbers in your array? Can you update your question with the markup of your `<select>` element?

Comment: Thanks again Frederic, yes, I'm certain the values are correct. The markup is actually being generated by the jtable plugin, so there is nothing I can post. I did notice however that I forgot to include a piece of code that should have been made part of my post. Can I post it here?

Comment: this is the piece of code I forgot to include in my post that should also be made part of this: `.attr({multiple:'multiple',name:'execs[]'})`

Comment: @NaN, if you're setting the element's name to `execs[]`, then you should match it with `find("select[name='execs[]']")` or it won't be found.

Comment: Frederic, I did that because I need an array of values on the server side and this was the only way I thought I could accomplish this. I will try changing this in your code and hopefully it will work

Comment: Frederic, thank you. It is working. I thought it matched on the id, not the name attr?

Comment: @NaN, well, you're using an attribute selector on `name`, not an id selector, so the `id` won't be used.

Comment: I see.. I guess I'm really tired. Thank you so much, Frederic. And, your solution is super clean and concise. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
            var values = "12,14,15";
            $.each(values.split(","), function (i, e) {
                $("select[name='execs'] option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
            });
```

Don't  forget to mark select multiple

```
    <select name="execs" id="strings" multiple style="width:100px;">
        <option value="12">A</option>
        <option value="13">B</option>
        <option value="14">C</option>
        <option value="15">D</option>
        <option value="16">E</option>
    </select>
```

**EDITED CODE**

you were reseting multiple attribute in every loop so on final loop you was getting only one value selected

```
        var values = "12,14,15";
        var select = data.form.find("select[name='execs']");
        select.attr({multiple:'multiple',name:'execs[]'});
        $.each(values.split(","), function (i, e) {
            $("option[value='" + e + "']",select).prop("selected", true);
        });
```

Comment: Raj, I get this: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select[name=execs] option[value="12"]"`

Comment: you have extra `"` in `'"]"` .

Comment: Thank you Tushar. I'll remove that quote.

Comment: Hmm. I'm only getting one value selected but not both.

Comment: Raj, it's still only selecting one value. There is one more line of code that I forgot to include in my post above. What I can see with the console is that code from this line I didn't include, is being placed in the option tag instead of in the select. Should I post it here or up top?

Comment: I can see that it definitely does work. I can't understand why it isn't working for me.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat, I forgot to include this in my post. I'm sorry, I'm just tired. Maybe this has something to do with it. `.attr({multiple:'multiple',name:'execs[]'})`

Comment: @rajeshkakawat, Thanks. Your updated code is changing all of my selects into multiple. Frederics code is working though

Comment: Raj, thank you for sticking with me on this! I really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: change to your selector data.form.find("select[name=execs]")

Comment: OK, I will try this now. brb

Comment: Raj, this is only giving me a single selected value. Frederic mentioned that it will match on the `name` attribute. Could this be why? When he edited his code to include my missing piece of code, it worked.

Comment: than you can select on id

Comment: I'm honestly lost here. I don't understand why your code doesn't work. I'm very new to JQuery so that doesn't help me. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41760/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-nan)